# ZuulPostFilter - Rewrite Location header

Tags: reverse-proxy, microservices, netflix-zuul

I configured Zuul as reverse proxy to a local backend server. Some responses have a 3XX HTTP code (redirect). I wrote the next filter to handle a rewrite of location header.

```
public class LocationHeaderRewritingFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private final UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
    private final RouteLocator routeLocator;

    public LocationHeaderRewritingFilter(RouteLocator routeLocator) {
        this.routeLocator = routeLocator;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return extractLocationHeader(RequestContext.getCurrentContext()).isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        Route route = routeLocator.getMatchingRoute(urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(ctx.getRequest()));
        if (route != null) {
            Pair<String, String> lh = extractLocationHeader(ctx).get();
            lh.setSecond(lh.second().replace(route.getLocation(),
                    ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path(route.getPrefix()).build().toUriString()));
        }
        return null;
    }


    private Optional<Pair<String, String>> extractLocationHeader(RequestContext ctx) {

        return ctx.getZuulResponseHeaders()
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> "Location".equals(p.first()))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

My Zuul configuration was:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    MyBackendService:
      paths: /hello/**
      url: http://localhost:8080/app1
      strip-prefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:
```

The filter worked just as expected but when I changed the 'url' to 'service-id' the filter fails to rewrite the header.

```
 zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    MyBackendService:
      paths: /hello/**
      service-id: APP1
      strip-prefix: false
      sensitiveHeaders:
```

The filter hangs due to wrong value that returned from `route.getLocation()` method, the new value is: APP1.

I am looking for a way to fix my filter, how I can extract the specific address that belong to my service id?